# Create a tag when @-symbol (@mention) is used

Tags: vb.net, comments, mention

When someone types @ and 'John' (in Teams for example), the name is embedded in an object that seems to have its own functionality, i.e. send an email to the person once the comment is saved.

In the absence of knowing what this functionality is called, where do I get more information about the (tag) object and how to embed it in the comment field (which is presumably a Richtext-field?

I'd like to use this functionality in a VB.NET project

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktag-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http